# How to access theme fonts using custom CSS style?

Tags: themes, css, fonts

I was looking to change the font in a specific location using a CSS Style. I am using the optimizer theme and I believe the library they us is the following:

https://fonts.google.com/attribution

I am trying to change the font specifically on to Cinzel on this paragraph but it is not changing. Here is what I have tried:

**Attempt 1:**
 < p style="text-align: center;font-size:300%;font-family: Cinzel;color:#124470">PLEASE CHOOSE YOUR SITE:< /p>

Apologies is this has been answered, however my search efforts didn't yield any results.

Thanks,

Comment: Can you please share your code? How are you embedding Cinzel?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The theme will likely only load a set of specific fonts, or will have options in the back-end to add extra fonts. Your problem is that Cinzel is not being loaded, if you insert the code below (preferably in to the `<head>`) you should find you can then utilise the font.

`<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Cinzel:400,700" rel="stylesheet">`